# Customize basic search form and provide appropriate search results

Tags: sugarcrm

In basic search form I have included checkboxes to detect duplicates on name & phone number.
How shall i proceed further.I have included fields on /custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/SearchFields.php and searchdefs.php.
Please help.

Comment: I answered the question "how do I configure the basic search screen," but I'm curious as to how you are detecting duplicates by way of checkboxes?

Comment: When the checkboxes will be selected I want to modify the search query.I know as how to add them from checkboxes but need to pass custom query when they are checked.But I dont know in which file I should do it.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM's Basic and Advanced Search field arrnagements can (and should) be configured using the Studio Tool. Log in as a System Administrator, click the Admin link in the top right corner and find the link for `Studio`

Within Studio, navigate to the module you're like to configure, go into Layouts, then Search, then Basic Search. The screen arrangement can be configured using drag-and-drop 'bricks' to represent the fields. All database fields for the module can be added to the Basic or Advanced search filters.

The screen can be configured using code, but I don't see why you would opt to do that. If you do, though, be sure to clear your cache using Repair and Rebuild or by enabling Developer Mode in the System Settings.